# Copy details from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script

Brand new to Google sheets but very familiar with Excel.

I have a spreadsheet with a summary page (named Summary)and several individual pages (named for that person i.e. Fred, Joe, George).

Each individual page is the responsibility of one person who enters data once a week.

I want to copy that individual information, which is on a single row to the summary page by having the individual start a function which copies the data from their sheet to the summary sheet.

One of the cells is =TODAY() which needs to be converted to a fixed date, the other cells in the row are just numbers.

This is so easy in Excel (just write a macro) but having trouble finding how to do it automatically in Google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `=TO_DATE(ABS(TODAY()))`

Comment: I probably could but I do not understand the language. For example how do I write a function to copy one row to another. I cannot see any COPY functions in the list list of functions?

Comment: You can use IMPORTRANGE formula. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en or you can write a basic AppScript to write a small function and add it to the spreadsheet menu, to let the user manually run the function when ever needed.